# Cloud Functions of Firebase failed to emulate

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to run `npm run serve`:

```
"build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
"serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
```

I get an output that says it failed to emulate my functions:

```
> npm run build && firebase serve --only functions


> functions@ build /Users/eliyacohen/apps/app-name/functions
> tsc


=== Serving from '/Users/eliyacohen/apps/app-name'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
⚠  functions: Failed to emulate payment-create
⚠  functions: Failed to emulate payment-process
```

When I open `firebase-debug.log` for further information, I see:

```
...
Sat Mar 31 2018 18:48:05 GMT+0300 (IDT)
[debug] [2018-03-31T15:48:06.665Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200
[debug] [2018-03-31T15:48:06.666Z] Starting @google-cloud/functions-emulator
[debug] [2018-03-31T15:48:08.254Z] Parsing function triggers
[debug] [2018-03-31T15:48:10.194Z] Error while deploy to emulator: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
[debug] [2018-03-31T15:48:10.195Z] Error while deploy to emulator: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5001
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
[warn] ⚠  functions: Failed to emulate payment-create
[warn] ⚠  functions: Failed to emulate payment-process
```

As far as I can understand, it couldn't reach 127.0.0.1:5001 so it could serve these functions locally?

I know that there's nothing wrong with my code, since `firebase deploy --only functions` deploys my functions with no errors.

I tried to remove entirely Node.js and reinstall it, downgrade and upgrade it. Same goes for the global modules.

My main folder (`../functions`) is built on Ionic Framework. Does it have something to do with this?

Environment:

- Running on MacOS High Sierra
- Node.js v6.11.5
- NPM version 3.10.10
- firebase-tools: 3.17.7 (Global)
- firebase-admin: ^5.11.0,
- firebase-functions: ^0.9.1

Comment: Did you try rebooting as well?

Comment: Having the same problem, when I copied and pasted my node modules from another older firebase project, firebase serve emulated the functions... prob should open an issue on github

Comment: Have you guys found a solution/updates for this one? It's really sad to keep deploying functions to test it

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella try to update to node 10, restart pc, remove node modules, and npm install again. make sure your dependencies are up-to-date

Comment: But doesn't it supports only Node 6 and - now Node 8 in the Beta?

Comment: @GuilhermeMatuella nonsense. I learned the hard way not to listen to that warning.

Comment: Yeah, I'm always skeptical about stuff dealing with Node versions as well. Thanks for the tip, I'll try it

Comment: I had a lot of problems with Cloud Functions. What i did was up a VM on compute engine, and implemented them as a normal nodejs server, it works faster and i have full control.

Comment: About your serve, AFAIKyou need to start serve from functions directory.

Comment: @Marco look at the comments. Upgrading to the latest version of nodejs solved the issue.

Comment: Right, thanks, still i stand to my point, I've deployed to my server and works very well, much better than Cloud Functions. I advise to do it, as being at googles desire is not a good idea. I had problems because they are updating node libraries, and they left me pretty much alone as i hadn't paid for Support.

Answer (score 0):

Since I see that lots of people are still encountering with the following error, try to update your node version the latest stable version (or >= 10)

Answer (score 0):

try with different port. example

```
firebase serve --port 3000 --only functions
```

Comment: The errors say that it couldn't connect to the *emulator*, this might not be a correct answer - but a good troubleshooting technique.